# Обработка невалидного AccessToken в vk sdk

Tags: android

Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию с помощью vk sdk. Проблема в том, что [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk) пишет, что для проверки невалидности токена нужно реализовать

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) { 
            if (newToken == null) {
                // VKAccessToken is invalid
            }
        }
    }; 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate(); 
        vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking(); 
        VKSdk.initialize(this); 
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно реализовать эту проверку в своем фрагменте. Как это сделать? Может проблема в том, что я не понимаю зачем нужно `extends Application`.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте `Activity` - собственно то, что отображается на экране. Советую почитать документацию или какие-то туториалы, коих в интернете полно. Используйте поиск.